# Integrating my database - Separate project or just merge it?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I'm creating a new MVC web application. I've never used MVC before (in asp.net). Anyway, in my last project, I used Code First and Entity Framework to handle my data and I enjoyed using that so I wanted to use it again.

Now, in the last project, I had a separate project/folder for handling the models and contexts, and I just referenced it into my main project. Would doing something like that still be the right choice in an MVC project, or should I just run it from the 'Models' section?

This is the website where I was learning how to implement this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/468777/Code-First-with-Entity-Framework-5-using-MVC4-and

Is there anything wrong with that approach or is it fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong.

If your project is not big enough go for it. Having just one project make it simpler though that you must keep the code organized

If your project might get large, then it would be a good choice to have two project or more for different layers and tiers of your application, such that different guys work on their own project.